# How to populate nested object in model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, ado.net

I'm creating a database first web api using entity framework. I created my models by creating ADO.NET Entity Models that were populated automatically with the fields on the tables that I selected. I want to be able to take some of those fields and group them in a custom object so when the xml is displayed, they are displayed as a child node.

An example is if I had the class with the following attributes

```
public class Person
{
  public string firstname{get; set;}
  public string lastname{get; set;}
  public string street{get; set;}
  public string city{get; set;}
  public string zip{get; set;}
}
```

I want it to be something like this instead

```
public class Person
{
  public string firstname{get; set;}
  public string lastname{get; set;}
  public string address{get; set;}//where address contains street, city, and zip
}
```

How would I go about in implementing this new Person class and populating the data of the custom object with my dbcontext

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to change three string properties to the one string property. How you can divide Address property to the street city and zip for example in case when street has two words?

You can create Address class (with three properties) and use it your Person class. But you will have problems when you try to regenerate/update your model - in such case is better to use code first approach.

Answer (score 0):

### Belongs-to Relationship

I think what you're looking for is a relationship between `Person` and a new class called `Address`.

To reference your new `Address` class inside `Person`, you would do the following:

```
public class Person
{
    ...
    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework will then associate an `Address` with the given `AddressId` with a `Person`.

Inside `Address` you can do something like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

### Eager Loading

To make sure an `Address` is loaded when a `Person` is loaded, you can use Entity Framework's [`Eager Loading`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) capabilities, such as:

```
context.Person.Include(x => x.Address)
```

Comment: I have a problem with this, apparently if you doesn't have the FK "AddressId" on this case for Person class is not going to load the object, I mean the Include just includes the nested objects that has addresses on it...

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerable List like

```
public class Person
```

{

public string firstname{get; set;}

public string lastname{get; set;}

public List  addresses{ get; set; }

}

public class Address
 {

```
public string street{get; set;}

public string city{get; set;}

public string zip{get; set;}

}
```

Comment: public IEnumerable<address> Addresses{get;set;} use like this